Laravel Dusk iterate through table rows
I cannot find any information in docs about iterating through html table.
I've tried
$browser->visit($link_yearly)
        ->with('table tbody', function($tbody) {
             foreach($tbody as $row) {
                dd($row->text('td:nth-child(1)'));
             }
        });

I get error
Call to undefined method Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::text()

I've tried to google but could not get any clear or up-to-date answer.

This works but I would prefer to iterate through row element.
$cell = $browser->text('table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)');


after you write a php function you need to put $browser before it
i believe to do this correct you need to do $browser->text($row . 'td:nth-child(1)')
